# Rails virtual attribute not available after save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm not sure if this is a problem within my app or my understanding of virtual attributes. Creating a `Member` object with a `first_name` and `last_name` virtual attribute works. However, when I go to retrieve the `Member`, the first and last name are nil. I say that it works because the `User.invite!` method it invokes successfully creates and saves a new `User` with the first and last name. My understanding is from this [article](https://jtway.co/rails-virtual-attributes-use-cases-cf33bd45e2a4) below, but I wanted to get some insight whether I was missing or misunderstanding anything.

> The Virtual Attribute is a class attribute, which has no
>   representation in the database. It becomes available after object
>   initialization and remains alive while the object itself is available
>   (like the instance methods)

Member

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :store
  belongs_to :user

  attribute               :email, :string
  attribute               :first_name, :string
  attribute               :last_name, :string

  before_validation       :set_user_id, if: :email?

  private

    def set_user_id
      self.user = User.invite!({
        first_name: first_name,
        last_name: last_name,
        email: email
        })
    end
end
```

Console

```
Loading development environment (Rails 6.0.0)
irb(main):001:0> Member.last
  Member Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" ORDER BY "members"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Member id: 55, store_id: 43, user_id: 3, created_at: "2019-09-03 02:05:27", updated_at: "2019-09-03 02:05:27", email: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil>
```

Comment: `email`, `first_name`, `last_name` should be added as table column (using rails migration) rather than virtual attributes, because you want it to get saved to database if I'm not wrong.

Comment: If you could explain what do you want to do with these 2 models, I can share you a better solution/explanation.

Comment: @coco I believe that `name` and `email` should be `User` fields.

Comment: There are a few instances where it would be preferable to call `member.first_name` rather than `member.user.first_name`, as it appears to do two lookups in my database.

Comment: `first_name`, `last_name` and `email` are actual columns on the User table.

Comment: What does `User.invite!` do?

Comment: @Coco it sends an invitation to a user, as part of `devise_invitable`

Comment: Ok, why not associate store to user directly? why need to have member object? Is the requirement many to many?

Comment: The `member` model is a join table, because a user can have many memberships. `first_name`, `last_name` and `email` are actual columns on the User table but there are a few instances where it would be preferable to call `member.first_name` rather than `member.user.first_name`, as it appears to do two lookups in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I didn't understand why you would like to use the `attribute` in this example. I believe that you want/should use [delegate](https://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate).

Basically, It seems to work when you invoke `invite!` because you probably are passing these attributes in parameters, so it initialize the object and set this "temporary variables". But, when you try to `SELECT` the register from database it's not there anymore.

As you flagged, `remains alive while the object itself is available`. Check that it says the **object**. When you do `Member.last` it initializes a new object with the data returned from database.

Comment: Cool, I've been seeing `delegate` lately but haven't familiarized myself with it yet. Also over-looked the object vs record statement. The `member` model above is just a join table. Can I delegate the first and last name attributes to the user or does that not make sense?

Comment: Yes, if they are is user fields.

Comment: @VegaStudios, please mark it as the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

I might go with this:

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :store
  belongs_to :user
end


class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :members
  has_many :stores, through: :members

  def self.invite_to_store(first_name, last_name, email, store_id)
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      user = invite!(first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name, email: email)
      user.members.create!(store_id: store_id)
    end
  end 
end
```

Then you can call `User.invite_to_store('first name', 'last name', 'example@gmail.com', 1)`